# Trying to append to CSV file using JS

Tags: javascript, html, csv, append

I am a complete beginner to JavaScript and other web technologies and am currently trying to append the data the user enters into the input form to a CSV file.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
<form id="form">
            Type the latitude of the crime: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
            Type the longitude of the crime: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
            Enter the date in which the incident took place: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
            <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit-btn" onclick="submitCrime">
        </form>

        
        <script>
            //Clear form once submitted
            function clearForm(){
                document.getElementById("form").reset();
            }

            function submitCrime() {
            var formData = $("form").serializeArray();
            let csv = "data:/Users/duvalbalogun-palmer/Desktop/VGIS/php-shit/assault.csv;charset=utf-8,"; // accept data as CSV

            formData.forEach(function(item) {
            csv += item.value + ";"; // concat form value on csv var and add ; to create columns (you can change to , if want)
            });

            var encodedUri = encodeURI(csv);

            clearForm();
        </script>
    </body>
</head>
```

Whenever clicking on the "submit" button, nothing happens. Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a number of things going on here

> <form id="form">

You are posting crime data, so form should have the attribute `method="form"' If what you posted isn't a part of a larger servlet / php / aspx file where you are handling the form submission, you should set the` action` attribute on your form.

> ```
>         Type the latitude of the crime: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
>         Type the longitude of the crime: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
>         Enter the date in which the incident took place: <input type="text" name="latitude"><br>
>         <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit-btn" onclick="submitCrime">
>     </form>
> ```

You need to change the `name` attribute in longitude and date. Also, while you are at it, change type to `number` and set min and max values for latitude and longitude, and date should be type=`date`

And as for your submitCrime function, you need to call `return true` at the end or the data won't get submitted.

```
<script>
    //Clear form once submitted
    function clearForm(){
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
    }

    function submitCrime() {
    var formData = $("form").serializeArray();
    let csv = "data:/Users/duvalbalogun-palmer/Desktop/VGIS/php-shit/assault.csv;charset=utf-8,"; // accept data as CSV

    formData.forEach(function(item) {
    csv += item.value + ";"; // concat form value on csv var and add ; to create columns (you can change to , if want)
    });

    var encodedUri = encodeURI(csv);

    clearForm();
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the help, @ControlAltDel ! I have made the changes to the script but still no success :( Do you think there is something wrong with the "let csv" variable?

Comment: @DuvalBalogun-Palmer Try stepping through in the debugger